# htaccess rewriteurl with dir returns 400

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having a problem rewriting the url:
http://example.com/admin/login to point to http://example.com/admin/index.php?a=login

By doing this I receive a Error 400 Bad Request
I'm also rewriting my home page the exact same way which works!

http://example.com/hello succesfully points to http://example.com/index.php?a=hello

I also verified that http://example.com/admin/index.php?a=login works which it does!

RewriteRules I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ admin/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Incase someone's wondering what my index rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]
```

Is my rewriterule wrong? Or is there something else?

Comment: I did once the same on my site my rewrite code is like this:    RewriteRule ^(/)?newURL/?$ /login.php [QSA,L]

Comment: Thanks, but this results in a 500 Internal server error

Comment: are you rewriting twice?

Comment: I removed my own first ofcourse

And as far as I know I'm not rewriting twice. Unless the second rule (which rewrites the home) rewrites it.

Comment: true, first you rewrite /admin/index.php then index.php, but only to be sure, can you try only to rewrite admin/index.php?

Comment: Removed it, didn't fix the problem

Comment: Dunno why, try http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/  or  http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php I hope it helps :S

Comment: Those sites didn't help unfortunatly

Comment: I can only reference to Apache rewrite Flags http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks anyways for trying

Comment: could you show full htaccess file? or fragment?